# Algorithm for searching in BST with only <

Tags: search-algorithms, binary-search-trees

How could one construct an algorithm for finding a node in a binary search tree that only requires the presence of $<$ on the key type. The ones I can easily also requires $=$.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show a specific example where there is no the presence of = on the key type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want to build a BST and you only have the $<$ operation, and you only know the algorithms with the $\leq$ operation, you can notice that :
$$a \leq b \Leftrightarrow \neg (a > b)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \neg(b < a )$$
Hence, using a negation in the right place, you can build your usual algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

You can test whether $a=b$ as follows: if it's not true that $a<b$ and not true that $b<a$, then it follows that $a=b$.

(Disclaimer: this requires that it be possible to order all of the elements using $<$, i.e., $\le$ be a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).  I imagine you were assuming this.  But if it's not, you're screwed anyway and the problem is not solvable -- binary search trees require a total order.)